# insert checkbox values in array into database

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have 3 checkboxes :

```
<input class="shoesChoice" name="trendy" type="checkbox" />
<input class="shoesChoice" name="luxury" type="checkbox" />
<input class="shoesChoice" name="sports" type="checkbox" />
```

And I want to store this information into (if possible) only one field in my database.
So, if the 1rst and the last input are checked, my shoesChoice field should have : "trendy, sports"

Comment: just concatenate the value server side.  explode : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php implode : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the name and keep them in value

```
<input class="shoesChoice" name="shoes[]" value="trendy" type="checkbox" />
<input class="shoesChoice" name="shoes[]" value="luxury" type="checkbox" />
<input class="shoesChoice" name="shoes[]" value="sports" type="checkbox" />
```

In PHP, try to get values in this way:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_REQUEST['shoes']))
 {
   $shoes = '';
   foreach
 }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like this :

$shoes = implode(" ", $_POST['shoes']);